# Cannot implicity List into IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, viewmodel

My ViewModel

```
public class ViewModelCT
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Tests { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedTests { get; set; }
    public Course course { get; set; }   
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{

    Course course = functionality.toCourse(functionality.GetCourseById(id));
    List<SelectListItem> lsli = new List<SelectListItem>();

    ViewModelCT vm = new ViewModelCT();
    foreach (SchoolService.Test sTest in functionality.GetTestByCourse(id))
    {
        SelectListItem sli = new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = sTest.Name,
            Value = sTest.Id.ToString(),
            Selected = false
        };
        lsli.Add(sli);
       // vm.Tests.(functionality.toTest(sTest));
    }

    **vm.Tests = lsli;**
    vm.course = functionality.toCourse(functionality.GetCourseById(id));
    return View(vm);    
}
```

And i get error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem>`.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I don't know why it is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error implies, `System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem` and `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem` are not the same thing. `ViewModelCT` and your controller are referencing different `SelectListItem` classes.

Check your using statements in each file.  I suspect one has `using System.Web.Mvc` and the other has `using System.Web.WebPages.Html`.